# Error to set up wordpress with Let's encrypt, Nginx on Docker

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, lets-encrypt

on the secure shell there was no error shown and It seems fine to be connected.
but I can not connect to my website (http://mrtrobotics.com)
I've got 502 bad gate way. would it be affected by nginx ???
I have no idea what to do. could anyone help me out please ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

```
  Name                        Command               State                     Ports
------------------------------------------------------------------------------           
certbot                    certbot certonly --webroot ...   Exit 0                                                      
mrtrobotics_db_1           docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up       3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
mrtrobotics_phpmyadmin_1   /docker-entrypoint.sh apac ...   Up       0.0.0.0:3333->80/tcp
mrtrobotics_wordpress_1    docker-entrypoint.sh apach ...   Up       80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp
webserver                  nginx -g daemon off;             Up       0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
    networks:
      - app-network

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: $MYSQL_USER
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_PASSWORD
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress/:/var/www/html/
    networks:
      - app-network

  phpmyadmin:
     image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
     ports:
      - "3333:80"

  webserver:
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    image: nginx:1.15.12-alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
  - ./wordpress/:/var/www/html/
  - ./nginx-conf/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
  - ./certbot-etc/:/etc/letsencrypt/
networks:
  - app-network

  certbot:
    depends_on:
      - webserver
    image: certbot/certbot
    container_name: certbot
    volumes:
      - ./certbot-etc/:/etc/letsencrypt/
      - ./wordpress/:/var/www/html/
    command: certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html --email elearning@wemakerobot.com --agree-tos --no-eff-email --force-renewal -d mrtrobotics.com -d www.mrtrobotics.com

volumes:
  certbot-etc:
  wordpress:
  db_data:

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name mrtrobotics.com www.mrtrobotics.com;

        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
                allow all;
                root /var/www/html;
        }

        location / {
                rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name mrtrobotics.com www.mrtrobotics.com;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        root /var/www/html;

        server_tokens off;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mrtrobotics.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mrtrobotics.com/privkey.pem;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
        add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
        add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
        # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
        # enable strict transport security only if you understand the implications

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off; access_log off;
        }
        location = /robots.txt {
                log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all;
        }
        location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }
}
```